# What does this sentence from a translation of The Idiot by Dostoevsky grammatical mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning

> That’s how you all are: keep company with dishonorable women, or with honorable women— there’s only one choice!

Maybe is there a way to write it without all these(colon and dash)? I can gather that the part after the colon is is opposite to how they so-called all are.

Comment: Dialog is often ungrammatical, or follows esoteric rules particular to the people or culture in which it takes place. This applies to real dialog in the real world, and also to dialog in books. The examples you have given appear to be part of a diatribe directed at a group. The person speaking may be attributing sentiments to the group as a form of critique. I wonder if including much more context might help people understand the sentences?

Comment: For the first it may mean the speaker will “be” a streetwalker because of wanting to carouse.

Comment: @mkeith This is from the book ‘the idiot.’ By the way can this(us talking) be considered a dialogue? Does this mean I don’t have to be grammatical?

Comment: I think if we were using text messages to chat in real time we could be ungrammatical. I believe communication via email or here in the comment section of a forum would be held to a higher standard. This is just my opinion, though. Not a defensible rule. Dialog spoken between two people in person is often ungrammatical, and since that is the norm, in novels, such dialog is also often ungrammatical, mimicking the way people actually speak.

Comment: Welcome to ELL. On this site, we only ask one question at a time. Also, if you're asking about the meaning of a whole sentence, we ask that you be very clear what specific parts of the sentence you're unsure about so we can focus just on those. I can think of several reasons an English learner might not understand the second and third sentences, but I don't know which ones apply to you.

Comment: If you mean _The Idiot_ by Dostoevsky, you should give that information in your question (and note that it must be a translation from the Russian, perhaps made some decades ago).

Comment: I read the comma within *"And now I want to carouse, I’m a streetwalker!"* as adding information, not stating a cause and effect relationship. Replacing the comma with *"because"* gives a cause and effect relationship. Compare to *"And now I want to dance, I’m wearing red shoes"*.

Comment: [Attribution: the good and the bad](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5679/attribution-the-good-and-the-bad) and [Should we take action on posts from experienced users with uncited quotes?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5781/should-we-take-action-on-posts-from-experienced-users-with-uncited-quotes)

Comment: @mkeith I see. Thanks a lot (:

Comment: @Mari-LouA I see, noted.

Comment: @AdrianHHH I see, it makes sense now. Wow, I didn't think of it this way.

Comment: @gotube Thanks for the welcome. For the second sentence, I can understand the part before and after the colon but I cannot seem to make a connection between these two parts.

Comment: @KateBunting I see, noted. Actually I wonder, is it because its a translation that the grammar at times sounds weird? Or maybe I have not read widely enough.

Comment: @rainsoupreme You've still got three separate questions there, so I can't help you until you focus this question down to just one very clear and specific question. You can use the "Edit" button above to improve it

Comment: If it's an older translation, it may include usages that sound odd to the modern reader. "You have described me as 'perfect' - well, I'm not exactly perfect if...".